# Why is Xcode 4.3.1 putting red strikethrough through this protected variable?

Tags: c++, xcode

[image]

Makes total sense that you can't access `myPrivateInt`. But `myProtectedInt` is totally accessible here (compiles fine). So why's it got that annoying red strikethrough running through it?

Xcode 4.3.1 using iOS SDK 5.1.

Comment: What if you don't use `this`? Does the autocomplete suggestion still have a strikethrough?

Comment: File a bug report: https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/. I would recommend sending them a link to this post as well.

Comment: XCode is just doing static code anlysis, so it may be wrong ;)

Comment: Good question. This is one of those slightly annoying things about Xcode which has hung around for ages. I've always just ignored it.

Comment: I'd just like to add that it's 2017 and this is still happening in Xcode 8. Defining protected methods in the CPP file and accessing protected inherited members both have strikethroughs in the suggestions box.

Answer (score 4):

Overriding a protected method in child a class with public access modifier is considered a compromising behavior by XCode. Even though  your code is syntactically correct , that strikeout text is a simple warning for you to revise your code to make sure you're not exposing one of your internally important class method to outside world.

Edit: Seems like an Xcode bug.

Comment: but... I'm not... overriding... anything

Comment: You may try accessing your protected variable via scope resolution operator. `Something::myProtectedInt;`

Comment: Have same problem: Autocompletion of protected ivar in (public) parent gives me the red strikethrough. Have tried scope resolution, to no avail. Would love to know why XCode thinks this should be discouraged, when it's valid C++.